# XCTest and the need for a special target to tweak App startup behaviour

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, unit-testing, xcode5, xctest

I am trying to implement XCTest as I have a bug in an iOS App which I don't seem to figure out so want to start building up get cases.

The App however, when loaded, will automatically connect to a server to update data. For the tests however, I would like this not to happen, as I need to clear the CoreData database and populate for each test.

Is there a way to know when e.g. building (on the target) if tests are going to be ran? Ie so I can use a flag to to leave out certain actions when testing?

Or should I just duplicate my normal target specifically for tests, and put in a flag that way?
(e.g. #if TESTING instead of #if DEBUG)

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but it might be a solution to your problem.

You could mock your class that does the server connection (ie fake the server connection).

You can do this by using OCMock that you can find [here](http://ocmock.org) or OCMockito that can be found [here](https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito).

Currently, I find OCMock easier to implement with XCTest than OCMockito. However, there might be some issues with OCMock as well, but those can be ironed out be looking at [this site](http://meandmark.com/blog/2013/10/getting-ocmock-to-work-with-xctest/).

Comment: Yes, that looks interesting, especially for higher level testing (where a server connection is needed) but it might be efficient enough for low level testing too (where normally I won't need a server connection etc. but only a few entries in the DB).

Comment: You could do check if the app is running in the simulator and just do your test using the simulator...

Comment: [Mocktail](https://github.com/square/Mocktail) is another tool in the same vein as the ones you mentioned. It's a bit less configurable, but also easier to set up: Just point it at a directory full of stubbed requests in a plain-text format.

Comment: @BillWilliams, thanks. Haven't used that one. Your link seems broken, I think the correct one should be https://github.com/square/objc-mocktail